# Black Screen After Login:: Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, resolution

I was going to switch monitors and the screen looked really weird and stretched so I changed the resolution. The next time I turned on my computer and logged in, the screen says it can not display. I switched back to the old monitor. I do not want to reinstall lubuntu, is there a way I can change the resolution back to auto without logging in?

Comment: Do you have access to the tty's? Do Ctrl + Alt + F1 gives you a command prompt?

Comment: or F2, for that matter

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Alt + F1 gives you a command prompt.

Open `/etc/default/grub` with your text editor with root privilege.

Add the following new line using your preferred resolution-depth from the list that vbeinfo gave you. It should be like this if you have a 1280x800 screen:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1280x800
```

Save the file and exit. (If you can't save the file you haven't opened it as root, go back and execute gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub providing your password.)

Execute the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Like what nicoX said, you can get to a console by ctrl+alt+F1-6,

But if you want a less permanent / more immediate solution, instead of modifying grub you could run `xrandr` which shows a list of possible resolutions(modes) for each active monitor, then `xrandr --output [adapter name] --mode [resolution_mode]`

If the * symbol in xrandr is being set to a higher resolution than your monitor can handle by default, then you can also delete those higher modes using it (something like `xrandr --delete-mode`)

This is a general xorg method, there may be a more elegant lubuntu-specific method